# What's aarch64's way to conditionally load/store?

Tags: if-statement, assembly, conditional-statements, arm64

I know that armv7 can use condition codes for load/store, like ldrne/streq. But A64 does not allow instructions to be conditionally executed. so how can i archive this in arm64:

```
ands    tmp1, dstend, 7 # set nzcv flag with ands
# if not zero, ldr w6, [srcend, -4]!, str w6, [dstend, -4]!
# else, do nothing and goes on
...
```

Comment: There are no such instructions on ARM64.  Consider performing a conditional branch around the load/store operation.

Comment: [Why are conditionally executed instructions not present in later ARM instruction sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22168992/995714)

Comment: what did you see in the arm documentation with respect to conditional execution or branches, etc?  what part of the documents did you not understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Predication of every instruction was a feature that made high-performance ARM CPUs harder to implement, especially with out-of-order execution. It was intentionally removed for AArch64.  ([Why are conditionally executed instructions not present in later ARM instruction sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168992/why-are-conditionally-executed-instructions-not-present-in-later-arm-instruction) quotes the vendor's own justification)

If you need something with side effects / possible faults like store and load to be conditional, you normally need to branch.

The only branchless option I can think of that seems worth considering would be `csel` with a pointer to a dummy location (e.g. on the stack) vs. the real location.  Then you still actually load and store, but not to the location you care about.  This is probably worse unless the branch mispredict penalty is high *and* the branch is hard to predict.

Comment: Predicated fault-suppressing load/store are coming back in some architectures, at least for SIMD, such as ARM SVE and RISC-V vector extensions, like x86 AVX-12.  x86 is even planning to introduce scalar integer conditional load/store with APX new forms of `cmov`.  (x86's normal CMOV with a memory source operand is just an ALU select operation fed by an unconditional load that *will* fault on a bad pointer.)

Answer (score -4):

```
void fun0 ( unsigned int x, unsigned int *y )
{
    if(x) *y=0;
    else  *y=1;
}
void fun1 ( unsigned int x, unsigned int *y )
{
    if(x) *y=10;
    else  *y=11;
}
void fun2 ( unsigned int x, unsigned int *y, unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    if(x) *y=a;
    else  *y=b;
}
void fun5 ( unsigned int x, unsigned int *y, unsigned int *z )
{
    if(x) *y=123;
    else  *z=123;
}
0000000000000000 <fun0>:
   0:   7100001f    cmp w0, #0x0
   4:   1a9f17e0    cset    w0, eq  // eq = none
   8:   b9000020    str w0, [x1]
   c:   d65f03c0    ret

0000000000000010 <fun1>:
  10:   7100001f    cmp w0, #0x0
  14:   1a9f17e0    cset    w0, eq  // eq = none
  18:   11002800    add w0, w0, #0xa
  1c:   b9000020    str w0, [x1]
  20:   d65f03c0    ret

0000000000000024 <fun2>:
  24:   7100001f    cmp w0, #0x0
  28:   1a831042    csel    w2, w2, w3, ne  // ne = any
  2c:   b9000022    str w2, [x1]
  30:   d65f03c0    ret

0000000000000034 <fun5>:
  34:   34000080    cbz w0, 44 <fun5+0x10>
  38:   52800f60    mov w0, #0x7b                   // #123
  3c:   b9000020    str w0, [x1]
  40:   d65f03c0    ret
  44:   52800f60    mov w0, #0x7b                   // #123
  48:   b9000040    str w0, [x2]
  4c:   d65f03c0    ret
```

Comment: This is not applicable to OPs scenario as the store itself is conditional, not the value that is stored.  The code you show will not work in such a situation.

Comment: @fuz asking the compiler is much easier than reading the docs, here showing there are some shortcuts but end of the day conditional branches as the per instruction conditionals are gone.  Although the docs should have been read before asking this question.  Demonstration that you can ask the compiler in a matter of seconds

Comment: I agree with that, but as your code does not show anything really similar to OPs scenario, it does not answer his question.  You do not even have any text explaining why the code would be relevant.  This makes your answer a bad one.